# How to retrive azure AD users and all their properties

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory

I want to get all of my users from my `Azure Active Directory` with all their properties using `C#`, but I cant find proper documentation about this topic which i can clearly understand like person who new to `Azure`. Can some of you show me some examples or samples which help me with this question.

I found some GitHub Samples which dont work or old and dont work.

I tried this

1. https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-snippets-sample
2. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations

All fields are set to `null`
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajsbI.png)

Comment: What have you tried? Which sites did you find, what code did you try? try this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations

Comment: Yes i tried this `Graph API` query unfortunately didn`t get all of props that i have in AD.

Comment: Well, what props does it lost ?

Comment: In response body i get only next fields: `UserPrincipalName, Given Name, Surname`. but i have a lot more, like department number etc.

Answer (score 0):

By default the Graph API returns a small set of standard properties about each user that your query returns. This is by design and ensures that if you have complex attributes on user objects you don't suddenly end up with a huge response object.

[Graph API supports OData queries](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters) which allow you to specify explicitly which properties you retrieve (and, no, there is no "select *" to retrieve all), the downside being you need to know the name of the properties you wish to read.

[Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) is a good way to familiarise yourself with how queries work, which you can then use in a Graph Client.

While this is for Azure AD B2C I quite like the Graph Client included in [this sample](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-GraphAPI-DotNet) as it is quite simple and should work with the standard AAD Graph API.

Comment: Nice this sample helped me to understand how MS Graph work, but can i do this without CMD, i mean fully automaticaly get list of my users on invocation of some method?

Comment: See the linked C# sample (last paragraph of answer). The exact answer will depend on the programming language you are using.